# SQL: Break Tie With a Subquery

Tags: mysql, sql

Suppose I have a MySQL table `signed_up` with columns `student_id, course_id, and marks`.  I want to get back the `student_id, course_id` and maximum `mark` for each student.  If the student received the same `mark` in multiple courses, I would like to take the row with the smallest `course_id`.  Finally, I'd like to display these results sorted by increasing `student_id`.

Here's my attempt which gives incorrect output:

```
select student_id, course_id, max(grade) from signed_up
where course_id = 
    (select min(course_id) from signed_up s where s.student_id = student_id)
group by student_id, course_id
order by student_id asc;
```

I get back a result set where `course_id` is all 1's to start.  That makes me think I'm messing up my subquery in the `where` clause.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Hope the following query will help:

```
select su.student_id, min(su.course_id), su.grade from signed_up su where
su.grade = (select max(grade) from signed_up s where s.student_id = su.student_id)
group by su.student_id order by su.student_id asc;
```

Comment: care to explain?

Comment: I think you need two step filtering. first one is taking  maximum mark for each student. In this query which is  su.grade = (select max(grade) from signed_up s where s.student_id = su.student_id). And the second one is taking minimum course_id for multiple occuring which is handled by group by.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this does what you want:

```
select su.student_id, su.course_id, su.grade
from signed_up su
where (su.course_id, su.grade) = (select su2.course_id, su2.grade
                                  from signed_up su2
                                  where su2.student_id = su.student_id
                                  order by su2.grade desc, su2.course_id
                                 );
```

This gets the maximum grade for each student along with the course with that grade.  If there are duplicates, the course with the smaller id is chosen.

You could also phrase this as a `group by` with a bit of a hack:

```
select su.student_id,
       substring_index(group_concat(su.course_id order by grade desc, course_id asc), ',', 1) as course_id,
       max(su.grade)
from signed_up su
group by su.student_id;
```